# Handling Unicode sequences in postgresql

Tags: json, postgresql, unicode

I have some JSON data stored in a JSON (not JSONB) column in my postgresql database (9.4.1). Some of these JSON structures contain unicode sequences in their attribute values. For example:

```
{"client_id": 1, "device_name": "FooBar\ufffd\u0000\ufffd\u000f\ufffd" }
```

When I try to query this JSON column (even if I'm not directly trying to access the `device_name` attribute), I get the following error:

> ERROR: unsupported Unicode escape sequence
>   Detail: `\u0000` cannot be converted to text.

You can recreate this error by executing the following command on a postgresql server:

```
select '{"client_id": 1, "device_name": "FooBar\ufffd\u0000\ufffd\u000f\ufffd" }'::json->>'client_id'
```

The error makes sense to me - there is simply no way to represent the unicode sequence `NULL` in a textual result.

Is there any way for me to query the same JSON data without having to perform "sanitation" on the incoming data? These JSON structures change regularly so scanning a specific attribute (`device_name` in this case) would not be a good solution since there could easily be other attributes that might hold similar data.

---

After some more investigations, it seems that this behavior is new for version 9.4.1 as [mentioned in the changelog](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/release-9-4-1.html):

> ...Therefore `\u0000` will now also be rejected in json values when conversion to de-escaped form is required. This change does not break the ability to store `\u0000` in json columns so long as no processing is done on the values...

Was this really the intention? Is a downgrade to pre 9.4.1 a viable option here?

---

<sub>As a side note, this property is taken from the name of the client's mobile device - it's the user that entered this text into the device. How on earth did a user insert [`NULL`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/0000/index.htm) and [`REPLACEMENT CHARACTER`](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/fffd/index.htm) values?!</sub>

Comment: For reference, this is not only the case with `SELECT` - I get the same problem with an SQL `UPDATE` statement on 9.5 and 9.6.

Comment: FYI I ran the `SELECT` you provided on a PostgreSQL 10.1, compiled by Visual C++ build 1800, 32-bit and it returned the same error.

Comment: I've recently stumbled upon the same problem when working on an app that interacts with PostgreSQL and was able to fix it in my client by just replacing this sequence with an empty string (in python it looks like this: `json_string.replace("\u0000", "")`

Answer (score 63):

`\u0000` is the one Unicode code point which is not valid in a string. I see no other way than to sanitize the string.

Since `json` is just a string in a specific format, you can use the standard string functions, without worrying about the JSON structure. A one-line sanitizer to remove the code point would be:

```
SELECT (regexp_replace(the_string::text, '\\u0000', '', 'g'))::json;
```

But you can also insert any character of your liking, which would be useful if the zero code point is used as some form of delimiter.

Note also the subtle difference between what is stored in the database and how it is presented to the user. You can store the code point in a JSON string, but you have to pre-process it to some other character before processing the value as a `json` data type.

Comment: Thanks for your input, @patrick. I've just made an edit to my post. The same problem does not reproduce in version 3.9.1 so at *some stage* it *was* considered a valid string. I'm not too happy about using such broad regex processing for every piece of data that is entering my system but at least I'll be able to use it if I'm in a tight spot and have no way out :) So, thank you.

Comment: Yep. A null byte isn't legal in a PostgreSQL string. Neither is a zero code point.

Comment: @CraigRinger - would it not be possible to just get a literal `"\u0000"` in the string response?

Comment: @Lix Yes, like the release notes for 9.4.1 indicated, you can replace `\\u0000` with `\\\\u0000` and you will get "FooBarï¿½\u0000ï¿½\x0Fï¿½" for "device_name" (tested on 9.4.4), but you would still have to `regexp_replace` the initial json.

Comment: Tested with 9.6, you can also just use `replace` instead of the regex version, e.g. `select replace('{ "a":  "null \u0000 word \u0000 escape" }', '\u0000', '')::json->> 'a' as succeeds;`

Comment: Is there any performance benefit of using replace over regexp_replace? @mark

Comment: TBH I did not benchmark it by I would assume so (string replace vs. pattern matching engine?) ‍♀️

Comment: Null is completely acceptable in a JSON string, does that mean that PostgreSQL has a broken JSON implementation? Since it can't handle every JSON format

Comment: Can we make this the accepted answer? I think it should be. It really helped me.

Comment: Better to fix regexp and use `(?<!\\)\\u0000` from another comment. You can check here: https://regex101.com/r/Zrxw22/1. Works correct with both `\\u0000` and `\u0000`

Answer (score 4):

I found [solution](https://p2d2.cz/files/jsonb-silver-bullet.pdf) that works for me

```
SELECT (regexp_replace(the_string::text, '(?<!\\)\\u0000', '', 'g'))::json;
```

Note the match pattern *'(?<!\)\u0000'*.

Comment: Thanks! This is the best! https://regex101.com/r/Zrxw22/1 - works correct with both `\\u0000` and `\u0000`

Comment: Thanks for this. I have been looking for a solution for so long!

Also, if anyone is using this in Python, don't forget to use raw string `r"(?<!\\)\\u0000"`.

Answer (score 2):

The solution by Patrick didn't work out of the box for me. Regardless there was always an error thrown. I then researched a little more and was able to write a small custom function that fixed the issue for me.

First I could reproduce the error by writing:

```
select json '{ "a":  "null \u0000 escape" }' ->> 'a' as fails
```

Then I added a custom function which I used in my query:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION null_if_invalid_string(json_input JSON, record_id UUID)
  RETURNS JSON AS $$
DECLARE json_value JSON DEFAULT NULL;
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    json_value := json_input ->> 'location';
    EXCEPTION WHEN OTHERS
    THEN
      RAISE NOTICE 'Invalid json value: "%".  Returning NULL.', record_id;
      RETURN NULL;
  END;
  RETURN json_input;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

To call the function do this. You should not receive an error.

```
select null_if_invalid_string('{ "a":  "null \u0000 escape" }', id) from my_table
```

Whereas this should return the json as expected:

```
select null_if_invalid_string('{ "a":  "null" }', id) from my_table
```

Comment: I had some issues with Patric solution as well but it was because I've tried to use it too late in the query - you need to fix your data soon, because seems like even operations like `json_array_elements` will fail. So just cast whole json you are working with to `text`, then replace and cast back to `json` and then the query should work.

Answer (score 2):

Just for websearchers, who strand here:

This is not a solution to the exact question, but in some similar cases the solution, if you just **don't want those datasets containing nullbytes in your json**. Just add:

```
AND json NOT LIKE '%\u0000%'
```

in your WHERE statement.

You could also use the REPLACE SQL-syntax to sanitize the data:

```
REPLACE(source_field, '\u0000', '' );
```

Comment: This would filter out all results containing the nullbyte. I was (almost 5 years ago hehe) interested in getting the data itself without the nullbyte included. It was pretty much a question of how to exclude just those characters without needing to sanitize the incoming data. Looking back it would probably have been a better idea to just clean up the data and make sure that no invalid json is inserted.

Comment: excellent, it's just what I needed. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

You can fix all entries with SQL like this:

```
update ___MY_TABLE___ 
set settings = REPLACE(settings::text, '\u0000', '' )::json
where settings::text like '%\u0000%'
```