# How to handle API responses(JSON) containing \x00 (or \u0000) in its data, and store the data in Postgres using django models?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, postgresql, django-models

I'm making an api call, and trying to store its response in Postgres using Django models.
Here's what I have been doing:

```
response = requests.post(url='some.url.com', data=json.dumps(data), headers={'some': 'header'})
response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
#handler is a object of a model
handler.api_response = response_data
handler.save()
```

But this used to fail, when my json had fields like `'field_name': '\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`. It used to give following error :

```
DataError at /api/booking/reprice/
unsupported Unicode escape sequence
LINE 1: ... NULL, "api_status" = 0, "api_response" = '{"errorRe...
                                                             ^
DETAIL:  \u0000 cannot be converted to text.
CONTEXT:  JSON data, line 1: ..."hoursConfirmed": 0, "field_name":...
```

How i tried to resolve this is by using the following:

```
response = requests.post(url='some.url.com', data=json.dumps(data), headers={'some': 'header'})
response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
#handler is a object of a model
handler.api_response = json.loads(json.dumps(response_data).encode("unicode-escape").decode())
handler.save()
```

The initial issue was solved then. But recently, when i got a field with value `'field2_name': 'Hey "Whats up"'`. This thing failed by giving error:

```
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting ',' delimiter: line 1 column 143 (char 142)
```

Probably because json.loads() got confused with `"` inside the value as an enclosing `"` and not an escaped `"`.

Now, If i print the initial response just after `json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))` statement, it shows the field as `\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00`.

But output of following code:

```
response = requests.post(url='some.url.com', data=json.dumps(data), headers={'some': 'header'})
response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))
print(json.dumps(response_data))
```

This shows the field as `\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000\\u0000`.
How does `\x00` change to `\\u0000`

And how do i save this field into postgres tables ?
This is what i could think of.

```
json.loads(json.dumps(response_data).replace('\\u0000',''))
```

To add this statement before saving to postgres.

Is there a better way ?

Is the code `response_data = json.loads(response.content.decode('utf-8'))` wrong ? Or causing not to escape that particular character ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

FWIW, I recently ran into this and your proposed solution also worked for me. I think it's probably the simplest way to deal with it. Apparently [this is the only character that can't go into a Postgres JSON column](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31672314/8207).

```
json.loads(json.dumps(response_data).replace('\\u0000',''))
```

Comment: strange that Postgres cannot handle this one character.